# How can I run a script from another script when I change folders?

Tags: python, path

Originally I had two scripts `main.py` and `call_main.py` They were in the same level.

In `call_main.py` I had

```
import subprocess

cmd = [
        "python3",
        "main.py",
]
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

No problem there.
However now I am moving the `call_main.py` script two levels deeper to a folder `/tools/mytools/call_main.py`

How should I modify the script to be able to call `main.py`?

In the beginning I tried changing the call to

```
import subprocess

cmd = [
        "python3",
        "../../main.py",
]
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

and changing any parameters that I call accordingly,

However it seems `main.py` call other scripts so when I do the above way, it cannot file some imports it does.

So any good way to be able to run main?

Comment: Running Python as a subprocess of itself is often an antipattern. A better solution is to `import` the code you want to run (you might have to refactor it to make this possible).

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not something I can question in the present situation